# Weak limit in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

i have following problem:

Be $1<p<\infty$, $T \in \mathbb{R}$, $f \in L^{\infty}( \mathbb{R})$
with $f(x+T) = f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$f'= \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f(t) dt$

with a sequence $u_n \subset L^p (0,1)$ and $u_n =f(xn)$

I want to show

$i)$ for $u_n$ we have weak convergence in $L^p (0,1)$ against
$f'$

$ii)$ find $lim ||u_n - f'||_{L^p}$

$iii)$ T=1 and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Find weak limit of $u_n$ for
 $$f = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\alpha &\text{on}& (0,1/2) \\
\beta &\text{on}& (1/,2) \\
\end{array} \right. $$

I think i solved i). However i dont know how to go on with ii) and iii).
I guess its $\frac {\alpha +\beta }{2}$ for ii)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to ii) is $||f-f'||_p$. In fact $||u_n-f'||_p$ does not depend on n!. To see this follow these simple steps: split $\int |u_n-f'|^{p}$ into integrals over the intervals $(kT,(k+1)T)$, k varying over all integers. In each term make the change of variable $y=nx$. Now observe that if a function g has period T then its integral over $(NnT,(N+1)nT)$ equals n times the integral over $(NT,(N+1)T)$. [The reason for this is we can split the integral into a sum of terms where each term is an integral over an interval of length $NT$; by periodicity g has the same integral over any of these intervals. Now just sum the terms you get as an integral over $\mathbb R$.